Dynamoose - Unable to retrieve DynamoDB `String set` vales
I'm having an issue with DynamoDB.
I have a table with some items that have an owners property which is of type String Set.
it would look something like this:
{
    "id": "123456",
    "name": "myItem",
    "owners": "{"987654321", "963852741"}"
}

In my NodeJS server I'm using dynamoose to handle the data.
Item Model
const ItemSchema = new Schema({
    id: { type: String, hashKey: true },
    name: { type: String },
    owners: { type: Set, schema: [String] },
});

ItemModel = dynamoose.model('Item', ItemSchema);

Item Controller
async function getIten(req, res) {
    // userId = '963852741'
    const items = await ItemModel.scan('owners').contains(userId).exec();
    // Items equals to `[]`, but it should be the existing item owned by id user (Isn't it?)
    res.json({items});
}

PartiQL Editor
If I try this query in the PartiQL editor, I get what I'm expecting:
SELECT * FROM "myDataBase.items" WHERE CONTAINS(owners, '963852741')

It may be ovious where the issue is, but I'm not being able to find it, or maybe I'm conceptually mistaken, any help is well received, thanks.
Basically what I'm trying to do is to filter a data from a DynamoDB table, based of one of their properties with a String set type.
I also tried having a filter, but it didn't work:
const filter = {
  FilterExpression: 'contains(#owners, :owner)',
  ExpressionAttributeNames: {
    '#owners': 'owners',
  },
  ExpressionAttributeValues: {
    ':owner': '963852741',
  },
};

ItemModel.scan(filter).exec();


is getIten a typo?

Yes, I didn't copy paste but wrote directly here

So the way I fixed this was just by adding a .all() function like this:
const items = await ItemModel.scan('owners')
    .all()
    .contains(userId)
    .exec();

Apparently my filter .contains(userId) was not working because I wasn't getting all of the documents.
